# C# backslashes in path

Tags: c#

I have currently a bug in my software which is only reproducible on customer side.
I am using Windows 10 (1805) and my customer uses Windows Server 2016 (Standard).

The problem is that when you set the image path with dialog box it seems that it is saved in a wrong format, but I am not sure.

```
// Snap (capture) an image to the memory
string path = IMGPath + "\\" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss") + ".jpeg";
```

IMGPath is given over the Windows FileDialog Box which is transfered correctly, but I cant debug on the customers computer.

Before the code above I have used "/" which may lead to the effect that image saving function couldnt find the correct path. But the strange thing is that on my own Machine Win 10 it doesnt have any negative effect, the images were saved in the correct folder.

Question: Is it possible that this may lead in Windows Server 2016 to problems?

Thanks in advance:)

Update:
Finally it worked, but the problem was that I have mixed up slashes and backslashes. Windows 10 corrects this automatically, but Windows Server 2016 not.

Comment: Have you tried `Path.Combine`?

Comment: Dont try to create paths yourself, use the already existing [`Path.Combine()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Please show us more contextual code. If we can see the entire codeblock we can help you more.

Comment: "saved in a wrong format" - did you mean that the *image* did save to the correct file, but in an incorrect format? If so, then please show where you save the image.

Comment: `but I cant debug on the customers computer` Unrelated to the question but in future, write errors to a log file that the customer can then send to you

Comment: actually I cant send more of the code, but saved image didnt save anything, the logfile my customer send me states that the no such folder/file found so therefor it shoudl be a path problem.

Comment: Does `IMGPath` exist? you can check by using `Directory.Exists(IMGPath)`

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of doing your own string concatenation that will reduce the potential for error here.

```
var path = Path.Combine(IMGPath, $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss")}.jpeg");
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss")` may be using the Clients Culture/TimeZone

Please try using `var date1 = DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`
and be aware of `TimeZone` issues.

Comment: Using `ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` in file name is not ideal: space, colon which are forbidden on windows...
If you want to deal with timezone, best is to use `DateTime.UtcNow`. Also, no culture with this format, it does not use ddd, MMM or so on (but timezone impact yes)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Path.Combine` method . which combines array of strings into a path.

```
string[] paths = {IMGPath, "\\", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss"), ".jpeg"};
string fullPath = Path.Combine(paths);
Console.WriteLine(fullPath);
```